# How to add sub columns in Mat table column of angular Material table

Tags: angular-material, angular-material-table

I am trying to create a mat table with sub columns using Angular Material Table like the link. Is there a way to do this with angular material table? Can I create sub columns from  one the columns? Please check the table from the below link

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

Answer (score 7):

Old question, but I had a similar problem and found this example. Angular Material version is 7.3.1. The complete project can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)

table-basic-example.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Header row first group -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="header-row-first-group">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef 
        [style.text-align]="center"
        [attr.colspan]="2"> 
      First group 
    </th>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Header row second group -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="header-row-second-group">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.colspan]="2"> Second group </th>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['header-row-first-group', 'header-row-second-group']"></tr>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

table-basic-example.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}
```

table-basic-example.css

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}

th.mat-header-cell, td.mat-cell {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: how to display mutiple groupings? in above case we have just one group, how to display mutiple and multilevel groupings?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I wanted a **multi-header data table** where the **2nd header** is in the **2nd row of the data table field** but didn't find any solutions related to **Angular Material**.
2nd header having ‘**Area**’, ‘**City**’, ‘**State**’ will be rendered below '**Address**' header, thus using *attr.colspan* value = 3

Also,  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['stub', ‘area’ , ‘city’, ‘state’]"> is added for 2nd header to work

Here is the solution I have implemented in my code using **colspan** attribute. Please refer to the comments mentioned in the code

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="model">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="header-font"> Model</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.model}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="header-font"> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="address">
        <th mat-header-cell [attr.colspan]="3" *matHeaderCellDef class="header-font"> Address </th>        
    </ng-container>
    
    <!--2nd Header-->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="stub">
        <th mat-header-cell style="background-color: white; border: none;" [attr.colspan]="2" *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
    <!--stub is necessary because 2nd header should not be placed below Model, Name-->
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="area">
        <th mat-header-cell class="header-font" *matHeaderCellDef> Area </th>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="city">
        <th mat-header-cell class="header-font" *matHeaderCellDef> City </th>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="state">
        <th mat-header-cell class="header-font" *matHeaderCellDef> State </th>
    </ng-container> 
<!--add 1 more ng-container for Penetration % field-->

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
     <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['stub', ‘area’ , ‘city’, ‘state’]"></tr>  <!--Enable this for 2nd Header-->
   <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

</table>
```

Comment: how to display mutiple groupings? in above case we have just one group, how to display mutiple and multilevel groupings?