# How to add mutiple header rows using angular material table

Tags: html, angular-material, angular5, angular-material-table

Parameter 1: Time Period
       {{element.value}} 
    
    
       Parameter 2: Gender
       {{element.gender}}

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="column3">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef rowspan="2"> Patients with Base Condition </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.value}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="column4">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Patients with Outcome</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.value}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="column5">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="ColumnDivider"> Prevelance </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="ColumnDivider"> {{element.value}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="column6">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Patients at Risk </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.value}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="column7">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> New Patients with Outcome </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.value}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="column8">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="ColumnDivider"> Incidence Proportion </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="ColumnDivider"> {{element.value}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="column8">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Total Patient Years at Risk </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.value}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="column10">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="myMarginLeft"> New Patients with Outcome </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="myMarginLeft"> {{element.value}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="column11">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Incidence Rate </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.value}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns">
  <div class="mat-header-row header-group-row">
    <div class="mat-header-cell" role="columnheader"></div>
    <div class="mat-header-cell" role="columnheader"></div>
  </div>
  <mat-header-row></mat-header-row>
</ng-container>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="getRecord(row)" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowIndex == row.inp_analysis_name}"></mat-row>
```

Multiple columns with a single column.

column1|column2|Column3|Column4|Column5|Column6|Column7|Column8
        Column2.1|Column2.2|Column2.3   Column6.1|Column6.2

Comment: [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/govlxyaejmg) you can find official example for mat-table with multiple headers.

Comment: Since I am using angular 5 it doesn't work using the above mentioned solution.

Comment: I found a solution to this problem ;[multi-header table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71153439/10141967)

Answer (score 18):

An example of re-creating multiple header rows and cell grouping using colspan.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

[image]

Comment: How we can subgroup in the second group again? Like thirdgroup which have weight and symbol while forth group have some other parameter like height?

Comment: I got `[style.text-align]="center"` not found error in Angular 11.

Comment: how to add third header lets say "group" which is grouping of "First Group" and "Secoind Group"?

Comment: i am not able to do something like `
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="big-header-group"></tr>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['header-row-first-group', 'header-row-second-group']"></tr>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>`

Answer (score 0):

The official solution was not useful for me because I needed the secondary header row to span all columns (this way I can use a separate component using content projection)

My solution is to create a SecondaryHeaderComponent which extends from CdkHeaderRow:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'mat-secondary-header-row',
   standalone: true,
   template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class SecondaryHeaderComponent extends CdkHeaderRow {}
```

Which can then be used like this (for example beneath the mat-header-row element):

```
<mat-secondary-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="[]; sticky: true">
   <p>2nd header row content!</p>
</mat-secondary-header-row>
```

One quirk I came across is that the table contents are still visible beneath the (sticky) secondary header row.